Export Access report to Excel file that will hold the report formatting
I need to export an Access report (that's already summarized a query).
The report has an unbound form that filters by a date range.
The form also has a Payment Date field (so it will post a Payment Date to the report).
I need to export this report to an Excel (xls) file used as a template (the raw, filtered data - since the formatting won't carry from Access to Excel) and then open and save a copy of the file (to not overwrite the file used as a template that will hold the report formatting in Excel).
I had successful tests with getting the raw query data filtered (not the pre-filtered report data).
I have not been able to deal with the form that contains the date range fields for filtering and a Payment Date field to post.
The SQL query gets in circular errors.
Public Sub Command49_Click()
Dim rst
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Set XL = CreateObject("excel.application")
Dim vFile

vFile = "C:\Users\hjohnson\Desktop\CHIP PAYMENT REQUEST TEMPLATE.xls"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from ChipPaymentList WHERE [Unload Date] >= [Forms]![Create Chip Payment List]![txtStartDate] & [Unload Date] <= [Forms]![Create Chip Payment List]![txtEndDate]+1")

With XL
    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open vFile
    .Sheets("Report").Select
    .Range("B5").Select
    .ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rst
    .ActiveWorkbook.Save
End With
Set rst = Nothing
Set XL = Nothing
End Sub


OpenRecordset() can't fetch the value from a text box, so it treats [Forms]![Create Chip Payment List]![txtStartDate] as a parameter for which you have not supplied a value.  For  strategies to deal with this, see How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?

Add VBA statements sParameter1 = [Forms]![Create Chip Payment List]![txtStartDate] before constructing the SQL statement and use the string 'sParameter1' from there

Replace the ampersand & in your SQL statement with AND keyword.

Welcome HJohnson! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

& is for concatenating strings. So, try with AND:
WHERE [Unload Date] >= [Forms]![Create Chip Payment List]![txtStartDate] AND [Unload Date] <= [Forms]![Create Chip Payment List]![txtEndDate]+1")


I did have that at first (and I just retried it). That does work either. Then I just get a Runtime Error 3061. Too Few parameters - 2 expected. One of the errors in my circle I've gotten.

Too few parameters is not a circular error. The query doesn't know about the form, thus cannot read the values. Retrieve these values and rewrite the query to include them.

I do have them in the query... they're set as criteria on the Unload Date field in the query settings.

Yes, but the query can't read them. Replace the parameters by first retrieving these values and rewrite the query to include the values.
